# Weird behavior of Dynamic + Rotate

Tags: dynamic

Check the following six piece of code:

```
Dynamic[Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], SessionTime[]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}], UpdateInterval -> 1]

DynamicModule[{s = 0}, Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], Dynamic[s++, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]]

DynamicModule[{s = 0}, {Dynamic@s++, Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], Dynamic[s, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]}]

Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], Dynamic[SessionTime[], UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]

Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], Dynamic[2 SessionTime[], UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
```

The first works fine. Rectangle in the second is obviously distorted and `UpdateInterval` is not working. However, similar to the previous one, the third works fine. The fourth refuse to update, while the first works well, and the fifth return a bug...

**Why would these happen?** Just feel so confused about `Dynamic` in Mathematica...

Comment: Your second expression behaves as you expect it if the whole `Rotate` expression is enclosed in `Dynamic`: `DynamicModule[{s = 0}, Graphics[Dynamic[Rotate[Rectangle[], s++], UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}], PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]]`. I cannot claim to fully understand why. However, I suspect that the distortion you observed from your original code may have been an artifact of graphics rendering.

Comment: @MarcoB I suspect that this is due to calculation issue instead of rendering issue. The error information in the 6th case indicates that there's something wrong with the rotation matrix. It seems that a `Cos` or something is missing. (My guess)

Comment: @MarcoB True, when `Rotate` is enclosed in `Dynamic` then it's fine